# Is SOAP communication mandatory for SAML?

Tags: soap, saml, rfc

Is SOAP a mandatory requirement for SAML communication? For SP initiated SAML, from [saml.xml.org](http://saml.xml.org/wiki/sp-initiated-single-sign-on-postartifact-bindings):

> 7. The SP's Assertion Consumer Service now sends a SAML message containing the artifact to the IdP's Artifact Resolution Service endpoint. This exchange is performed using a synchronous SOAP message exchange.
> 8. The IdP's Artifact Resolution Service extracts the MessageHandle from the artifact and locates the original SAML  message associated with it. This  is then placed inside a SAML  message, which is returned to the SP over the SOAP channel.

But [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Security_Assertion_Markup_Language) mentions that it's optional.

> On the back channel, SAML specifies the use of SOAP 1.1. The use of SOAP as a binding mechanism is optional, however. Any given SAML deployment will choose whatever bindings are appropriate.

So which is correct? Does SP SAML require SOAP for communicating with the IdPs (any third party ones) or is it optional? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SOAP is not required. The saml.xml.org article states

> For this example, the POST Binding is used to deliver the SAML 
>   message to the IdP and the Artifact Binding is used to return the SAML  message containing the assertion to the SP.

In this example the artifact binding is used. And when the artifact binding is used to transport a message, another method, than the one used to send the artifact, must be used to resolve it. The method used to resolve the artifact can not use the browser, like redirect or POST.

This is only if your use the Artifact binding. If you use another binding to transport the message, for exampel HTTP redirect or POST, there it no need or requirement for SOAP.